# How to run an ASP.NET website in Raspberry PI

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run my ASP.NET website (created in Visual Studio c#)

I followed this Steps:

1. I installed Raspbian OS as operating system for the Raspberry pi
2. I enabled SSH connection
3. I published my website so that is able to run on Linux device
4. Then I copied the publish folder on my Raspberry (using WinSCP)
5. I tried to run the Website with Powershell, I got this message:

```txt
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /home/pi/web/Modellfabrik
    info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[62]
          User profile is available. Using '/home/pi/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Hosting environment: Production
    info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
          Content root path: /home/pi
```

6. When I tried to run the website on my browser using:
   `http://myraspberryipadress:5000` but it does not work

Comment: what are you hosting the website with? kestrel?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is without more information, but for sure the application is now listening only for connections from localhost: `http://localhost:5000`. Reconfigure the application to listen on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: you're only listening on localhost. not on any public interface. update your launchsettings.json

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time, but still...

Raspberry spins only `http://localhost:5000` and `http://myraspberryipadress:5000` will not work.

You have to add to your "appsettings.json" this line `"Urls": "http://[::]:5000"` or `"http://[*]:5000"`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have port 5000 open on your raspberry pi.

Run `nmap -sT -p- <192.168.0.X.X>` to see the list of available ports open on your pi.

Check out an article like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69123/how-to-open-a-port) for how to open that specific port.

Or - even *safer*, setup a reverse proxy nginx server on the pi. [Link](https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/setup-an-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-a-raspberry-pi-or-any-other-debian-os/)